# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) how can i resolve this issue

Tags: python, opencv

i am doing blob detection in python getting this error at the end how can i do this?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image=cv2.imread("SunFlowers.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
Detector=cv2.SimpleBlobDetector()
key=Detector.detect(image)
cv2.drawKeypoints(image,key,[0],(0,255,255),cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

cv2.imshow("sunflower",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The error appears at this line:

```
key=Detector.detect(image)
```

Comment: The error appears after which line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5008845

Comment: key=Detector.detect(image) error appears in this line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same error but I've fixed it using that function

```
Detector=cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()
```